# Non-public distribution of an Android application?

Tags: android

I’m in the process of researching if and how a Windows Mobile .NET application can be ported to Android. The question that I’m into right now is how to distribute and update the application once it’s developed.

The current .NET application is “installed” on a device using an appropriate system image.  The program then updates itself by downloading new updates from a website during usage and installing those updates on the next start-up.

So now the question is: **how is this task best performed with an Android application?**

I’ve received indication that the company would like to get away from using images so more devices can be supported, so using images isn’t a requirement.

However, it is an application internal to the company and as such no external users are to be able to download it, so simply putting it on the Android market for anyone to download isn’t an option.

Does anybody know if there is an “easy” solution to this problem in the Android world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using android market not an option - than you'll have to write it yourself
I would
1) Set interval of how often you check for updates.
2) On start of your application i'd check for update ( comparing version of your app and available version ) and if it's available present user a dialog - update is available pls download. 
3) Once user downloads the app, it'll be installed and upgraded.
You don't need to worry about different devices - if you do it right - one apk fits all.

Comment: That's pretty much how it's done in the current .NET application, although the user is never notified about the new version, it's being downloaded in the background and installed automatically when the user relaunches the application. I was hoping for a solution that didn't require any programming on my behalf though, something like the ClickOnce solution in .NET

Comment: That implemented through market. But you not able to use it. And you won't be able to install it automatically. The dialog will be presented. For a short time while market was not supporting update people were doing pretty much what i described.